# range in scale_numeric in ggvis R

Tags: r, ggvis

Could anyone know why range in scale_numeric in ggvis does not work correctly?

```
library(ggvis)
mtcars %>%
  ggvis(~wt,~hp) %>%
    layer_points() %>%
    scale_numeric("x", range = c(2,3))
```

**update**

when I use `domain = c(2,3)` this is result:

[image]

**next update**

Ok, after using `domain = c(2,3)` with `clamp = T` the result is better but still it is not expected outcome.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `scale_numeric("x", domain = c(2,3))`?

Comment: try using @jazzurro's solution with `clamp=T`

Comment: otherwise, just replace mtcars with mtcars[mtcars$wt>2 & mtcars$wt<3,]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @NicE and @jazzurro I figured it out. Additionally, I have to add something more, when I have just one dot point. I mean I add not only `scale_numeric("y",...)` but also `scale_numeric("x",...)` because without it, it does not look well.

```
df <- mtcars[mtcars$wt>2.4 & mtcars$wt<2.5,]
df %>%
  ggvis(~wt,~hp) %>%
    layer_points() %>%
#   try with and without scale_numeric("x",...), and see what happened
#   scale_numeric("x", domain = c(2,3), clamp = T, nice = F) %>%
    scale_numeric("y", domain = c(50,100), clamp = T, nice = F)
```